# Python можно ли убрать cmd geckodriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

я хочу убрать cmd у geckodriver что бы бот работал в фоновом режиме как это сделать?

geckodriver версии 0.28.0

Comment: Укажите ОС.....

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Windows 10 home

Comment: как понимаю вы хотите убрать отображение консоли? переименуйте расширений файла в *.pyw. Можно запускать как pythonw script.py(w)

Comment: @Kers файлы c расширением *.pyw лучше открывать через pythonw, если через python, то это надо лезть в документации, чтобы настраивать + могут понадобиться права админа

Comment: @SlayerLeon Leon обратите снимание что в комментарии выше указан как раз таки pythonW.